# Make the "About me" height auto-fit the content

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

It would be great if we could see all the info in the **About Me** container instead of going down using the scroll bar. I have seen many user pages where I need to use the scroll to see the entire profile information.

**An image:**

[image: About me]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So J. Random Funnyguy can put 750 `<br>`s in his profile text?

Scroll down to see the answers – where have I heard that before? :)

Not going to happen.

Comment: I always knew @random was a troublemaker.

Comment: Okay. Can't we at least duplicate the size of it? Or just trim the empty lines, like if the user enters more than 5 consecutive lines, keep only 5? Of course, he could write a line, and 5 spaces, a line, and 5 spaces, but I don't really think that's the idea of any user here.

Comment: @Oscar the point is: This change (even with that restriction) changes the layout of the user profile unpredictably -- and the *usual* thing people care about is the user's questions and answers. How often do you need to see the 17th line of the "about me" text *immediately*?

Answer (score 5):

Shoving useful content down the page is not a good idea, but I wouldn't mind a "Click here to view About Me on a fullsize page" link.

Comment: STACKOVERFLOWBLOGS!

Answer (score 2):

To confirm @balpha's post:
[image]
[image]

---

I removed the CSS-rule with Web Inspector.

Comment: That looks like *far* less than 1500 `<br>` tags.

Comment: But it comes close.

Answer (score 1):

I partly agree.  The current box is too small; it could stand to be twice or three times as large as it currently is.

Comment: Meh. It's easily three times too large.

Comment: @Shog9: height and max-height?